# Is this subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ open or closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $G=\{\langle x,y \rangle \mid x+y=1\}$. Show if $G$ is open or closed in $\Bbb R^2$.

My idea is to show G is closed, since its complement $G^c $ is open.
where $G^c=G_1\cup G_2$. where $G_1$ and $G_2$ are two open subsets of $\Bbb R^2$ defined as below.

$G_1=\{\langle  x,y \rangle  \mid x+y>1\}$
$G_2=\{ \langle x,y \rangle  \mid x+y<1\}$

First of all, what do you think about my idea?
(Is this a legitimate way of proving closedness!?)

And then what is the main or general method of proving a subset is open?

I am studying Real Analysis book by Goldberg, which is really not a good book to self study. so if there is any GOOD tutorial or textbook to self study metric spaces, please introduce also here. Thanks

Comment: One way you can do it is to show that the limit of any sequence of vectors in $G$ will also be in $G$.

Comment: Do we require $x$ and $y$ belongs to a set $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: This should work. A set is closed if its complement is open. The union of two open sets is open. How do you plan to prove those sets are open? Do that and you are good to go. 

BTW there are multiple ways to determine which sets are open. Metric spaces, stipulated topologies.

Comment: Checkout my edits showing how to use `\langle` and `\rangle` for nicer formatting, and `\mid` instead of the vertical bar to get nicer spacing in your set-description notation. Also `\Bbb R^2` to get prettier formatting for the real numbers.

Comment: "Assume" is strange here. "Let $G=\ldots$" is preferable.

Answer (score 3):

$f(x,y)=x+y$ is continuous, hence $f^{-1}(1)$ is closed.  Since $\Bbb R^2$ is connected, the set is not also open.

BTW, your $G_1$ and $G_2$ are open, since, for instance, $G_2=f^{-1}((-\infty,1))$, and $(-\infty, 1)$ is open.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x_n,y_n) \rightarrow (a,b)$.

Then $x_n \rightarrow a$, and $y_n \rightarrow b$.

Need to show that $(a,b) \in G$, i e. $a+b=1$;

$\epsilon$ given.

There is a $n_0$ s.t. for $n \ge n_0$

$|x_n-a|<\epsilon$, and $|y_n-b|<\epsilon.$

$|-a-b +1|=$

$|(x_n-a)+(y_n-b)+(1-(x_n+y_n))| $

$\le |x_n-a|+|y_n-b| <2\epsilon.$

Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary we get

$1=a+b$, i.e. $(a,b)\in G$.

Comment: this reminds me of the limit of the sequence. is this a definition for continuity?

Comment: Yes, an equivalent definition of a limit, or for $x_n \rightarrow a$ and $L=f(a)$ continuity.